# Linq-To-Sql select view, update table

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

Can I use view on selects and table on other operations? I tried to do that with inheritance, but nothing helpfull.

```
Update or insert of view or function 'dbo.MyView' failed 
because it contains a derived or constant field.
```

Getting this error

**UPD**

I understand that I should only remove column from a list on insert, what I do that with IsDbGenerated.

Comment: Can you provide the definition of your view?

Comment: You might want to switch to EF4, which has support for Views for read and the SPs for write.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably caused by:

"The columns being modified in the view must directly reference the underlying data in the table columns. The columns cannot be derived in any other way, such as through the following:

An aggregate function: AVG, COUNT, SUM, MIN, MAX, GROUPING, STDEV, STDEVP, VAR, and VARP.

A computation. The column cannot be computed from an expression that uses other columns. Columns that are formed by using the set operators UNION, UNION ALL, CROSSJOIN, EXCEPT, and INTERSECT amount to a computation and are also not updatable."

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx